# "The Hero as Werwolf": why that spelling for werewolf?

Tags: short-stories, title-explanation, gene-wolfe

["The Hero as Werwolf"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2666792-the-hero-as-werwolf) is a short story by Gene Wolfe. Quoting the synopsis from [here](https://reiszwolf.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/the-hero-as-werwolf-%E2%80%A2-1975-%E2%80%A2-posthumanity-sf-short-story-by-gene-wolfe/):

> It *[sic]* the late 21st century, humanity has evolved into a master race with some people left behind. Those sorry, savage people have nothing to eat and so they went cannibalic. Protagonist Paul is on the hunt for a pair of masters when he meets a father with his nearly bestial but beautiful daughter.

**Why is "werwolf" spelled in this way rather than the more standard "werewolf"?** Is it just a way to make Wolfe's title more distinctive and memorable compared with other wer[e]wolf literature, or is there some deeper purpose to it? Wolfe is a writer who makes deliberate choices for often very subtle or hidden reasons, so I'm not dismissing it too easily as a gimmick. For what it's worth, the Old English root of [werewolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf) was *werwulf*, so this could be an older form of the word?

Comment: Werwolf is the German spelling. ([Der Werwolf](https://kalliope.org/en/text/morgenstern2002012949) is a funny poem by Christian Morgenstern.) I don't know if that explains anything, as I don't know the Gene Wolfe story.

Comment: German Wikipedia claims that the word is a compound of "wolf" with the germanic word for "man", which is "wer", so Gene Wolfe might have used a more "original" spelling.

Comment: "Werwolf" is an acceptable, though unusual, speling of werewolf, according to the dictionary. Something similar also occurs in Wolfe's "Peace", where the central character, Algernon Weer, is hinted to be a "weerwolfe"  ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This was addressed by Wolfe himself in *'[The Best of Gene Wolfe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4395088-the-best-of-gene-wolfe)'*

> **AFTERWORD**
> Ever since this story appeared, I have been getting heat for
> my spelling of werewolf. I reverted to the original spelling to point
> up the meaning of the word: “manwolf.” We would be more apt to say
> “wolfman,” though the ideas conveyed are distinctly different. Our
> werewolf is a man who becomes a wolf. The manwolf envisioned by the
> Anglos and Saxons was a man to be feared as wolves were feared, and
> for the same reasons.
>
> *Wolf-wise feigning and flying,*
> *and wolf-wise snatching his man.* —KIPLING
>
> Wer was the original Anglo-Saxon word for the male of the human
> species. (Man designated a human being. We see the ghostly traces of
> this when we say, for example, that Molly Pitcher manned a gun at
> Monmouth.) I wanted the old original import, and so titled the story
> you have just read as I did.